# How to add "a" shortcut to VSCode for creating a file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to use Atom where I could select a folder in the explorer sidebar, press "a", and then this would create a new file.

I thought I had finally gotten this command to work in VSCode by

1. Setting up the keyboard shortcut for `File: New File` to be `A` with a `When` of `sideBarFocus`
2. [Disabling file filtering](https://superuser.com/questions/1417361/how-to-disable-file-filtering-in-vs-code-sidebar-explorer)

This configuration allows me to create a new file by pressing "a".

However, if I try to rename a file to contain the letter "a", I cannot, because as soon as I press "a" it tries to create a new file.

**I would like to be able to name files to contain the letter "a".** (While having "a" still allow me to create a new file when I'm not renaming.)

How can I fix this?

Comment: use `Ctrl+A` in the key binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another negated when clause to your keybinding:

```
    {
        "key": "a",
        "command": "explorer.newFile",
        "when": "sideBarFocus && !inputFocus"
    }
```

so it won't operate when an input box has focus.